# Call methods of sub-activity from base activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, action

I have a base activity containing action bar.  I have options like: share, refresh in the action bar. But those methods are written in the fragments and  have the instance of the fragments in another activity which is extending the base activity. So how to get the instance of the activity containing fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SubActivity`, define a member:

```
private SubActivity instance = this;
```

and also define a method:

```
public static Activity getSubActivityInstance(){

      return instance;

}
```

In your `BaseActivity`, you can then use:

```
SubActivity mySubActivity = SubActivity.getSubActivityInstance();

if(mySubActivity != null){

    // now call methods defined in SubActivity class

}
```

This will only work after an instance of `SubActivity` has been created (obviously), not before.

Comment: mParserContext=(ParserActivity)this;- I  tried like this in my base activity..and it worked..Thanks for the idea